why do we need to add 0.5 to the texture coordinates?
in WebGL, to access a pixel of a texture you must use the following formula:
texture2D(oneTexture, vec2( (i + **0.5**) / width , (j + **0.5** ) / height ) )  

i and j are integers representing the position of the element in the texture
Indeed, in the code below, the formula works, but it also works if we do not add 0.5.
My question is, why do we need to add exactly 0.5?
and I would like to see an example where not adding 0.5 would not work


"use strict";

let vertex=`
    void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(0,0,0,1);
    gl_PointSize=1.0;
}`;

let fragment=`
    precision highp float;
  
  uniform sampler2D image;
  
  void main() {
    
    //WHY 0.5 ? offfset=0 doesk work
    float OFFSET = 0.5 ;  
    
    gl_FragColor = texture2D( image,
                                                    vec2(
                                (3.0 + OFFSET ) / 5.0,
                              (2.0 + OFFSET ) / 3.0
                              
                              // (3,2) is the coordinates of darkgoldenrod
                           ));
  }`;
  
  let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  canvas.width=3;
  canvas.height=3;
  
  let gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  let program = gl.createProgram();
  const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertex);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragment);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  let texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  
  const blueviolet  = [  138, 43, 226 ,255];
  const brown  = [       165, 42, 42,255];
  const burlywood  = [      222, 184, 135,255];
  const cadetblue    = [    95 ,158 ,160,255];
  const chartreuse = [      127 ,255 ,0,255];
  const chocolate = [       210, 105, 30,255];
  const coral    = [     255 ,127, 80,255];
  const cornflowerblue = [       100, 149, 237,255];
  const cornsilk   = [     255, 248, 220,255];
  const crimson    = [     220 ,20, 60,255];
  const cyan   = [     0 ,255, 255,255];
  const darkblue = [       0, 0, 139,255];
  const darkcyan   = [     0 ,139, 139,255];
  const darkgoldenrod   = [      184, 134, 11,255];
  const darkgray   = [     169 ,169, 169,255];
  
  gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA,    
    5,          
    3,        
    0,   
    gl.RGBA,
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    new Uint8Array([
    
    //  ----- 0 ---------- 1 -------------- 2 ---------------- 3 ---------------- 4 -------- 
    
      ...blueviolet,  ...brown,     ...burlywood,       ...cadetblue,     ...chartreuse ,  // 0
      ...chocolate,   ...coral ,    ...cornflowerblue,  ...cornsilk,      ...crimson,      // 1
      ...cyan,        ...darkblue,  ...darkcyan,        ...darkgoldenrod, ...darkgray      // 2
      
      // coordinate of darkgoldenrod is  (3,2)
      ])
  );
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width,gl.canvas.height);
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
  
  gl.drawArrays( gl.POINTS, 0, 1);
canvas {
        width:300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color:green;
        image-rendering: pixelated;
      }
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>




0.5 is the center of the pixel. Further reading: https://www.realtimerendering.com/blog/the-center-of-the-pixel-is-0-50-5/

You don't if the texture sampler filter function is "NEAREST". However if it is "LINEAR" you have to calculate the center of a pixel if you want to get the actually color of a pixel and not an interpolated color.

@Rabbid76 ok, so that means that when we use textures to store data (position, speed, ...), and therefore we set the filter to nearest, it is useless to add 0.5

@oceanGermanique Yes, exactly. Textures that contain data should be looked up using ‘NEAREST’ (or texelFetch, which is available in GLSL ES 3.0 / WebGL 2)
